# How can I align the center of a background image with the left side of it's containing div?

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

It's really easy to align the center of a `background-image` with the center of the div via `background-position`.  I can't see any way to align the center of a `background-image` with the left side of the div though.

I've tried playing with all sorts of different percentages for `background-position`, but I haven't been able to see how exactly the % is calculated outside of 0-100%.  I know 0% is left of background with left of div, and 100% is right of background with right of div.  But what is -50% or 200%?  I think it's adjusting by a ratio of the width of the two items, which is pretty meaningless outside the range.
[I made this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJv8I.jpg) to try see if I could figure something out.

Anyone have any other suggestions to get the center of a `background-image` aligned the left side of the div it's set on?

Comment: let me know if the duplicate is enough detailed to help you figure out the calculation ... you will find all the needed relation and formula.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly - you want to align background image center to be on left side of the div. Then maybe try this!

```
<div class="yourdiv" >
 <img class="yourbg" src="" >
</div>

<style>
*{
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.yourdiv{
  width: 500px; height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.yourbg{
  width: 100%; height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
}
</style>
```

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/e4w6stmc/

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty simple and what I did.  I'm specifically referring to background-image though, so this isn't related to my question but a work around.  I do see I wasn't as clear as I could have been with the question. Fixing that.